# where employer.employees.gender = 'm', or how to filter a list of Items on a field of Item?

Tags: hibernate, select, join, filter, hql

An employer has many employees (a one-to-many relationship). Here is how I select the employees for a given `:employer`:

```
select employer.employees
from Employer employer
where employer = :employer
```

I would like to filter the results to get only the employees which `gender` field is `m`. How could I achieve this using HQL? Is there any clause that I haven't noticed in the [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)?

Ideally, something like:

```
and employer.employees.gender = 'm'
```

Or:

```
and each(employer.employees).gender = 'm'
```

Comment: You are going in right direction.. Are you getting some error this and condition ? 14.9 in your mentioned doc has similar example..

Comment: @Meherzad The examples of 14.9 are for many-to-one relationships, while I'm working on a one-to-many one, and this is precisely the point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT ey.name
FROM Employer employer
LEFT JOIN employer.employees ey
WHERE ey.gender = 'm' AND employer = :employer
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would do the job, but it will return an Employer instead of the list of its Employees...